# how to convert nginx-ingress annotations to --set format to enable prometheus metrics

Tags: annotations, nginx-ingress, prometheus-operator

I want to set annotations on command line while installing nginx-ingress. my values.yaml file looks like below and i want to use command line argument instead of values.yaml file.

```
controller:
  metrics:
    port: 10254
    enabled: true
    service:
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
        prometheus.io/port: "10254"
    serviceMonitor:
      enabled: true
      namespace: monitoring
      namespaceSelector:
        any: true
```

I tried following arguments but its giving error

```
 --set controller.metrics.service.annotations."prometheus\.io\/scrape"="true" --set controller.metrics.service.annotations."prometheus\.io\/port"="10254"
```

Error:

```
Error: release nginx-ingress failed: Service in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Service: v1.Service.ObjectMeta: v1.ObjectMeta.Annotations: ReadString: expects " or n, but found 1, error found in #10 byte of ...|io/port":10254,"prom|..., bigger context ...|,"metadata":{"annotations":{"prometheus.io/port":10254,"prometheus.io/scrape":true},"labels":{"app.k|...
```

Any suggestions how exactly these annotations should be passed ?

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same issue! When you look at the chart, they define it as a string. So when I utilize the command below it successfully sets the values. The trick is to utilize `--set-string` rather than `--set`

```sh
helm upgrade ingress-controller ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --namespace ingress-nginx --set controller.metrics.enabled=true --set-string controller.metrics.service.annotations."prometheus\.io/scrape"="true" --set-string controller.metrics.service.annotations."prometheus\.io/port"="10254"
```

Showing that the values are set when we validate this with `helm get values ingress-controller --namespace ingress-nginx`

```sh
controller:
  metrics:
    enabled: true
    service:
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/port: "10254"
        prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
```

Now if you would like to get the details into prometheus, then it appears that this did not work for me though. I had to utilize the `controller.podAnnotations` to get this working:

```sh
helm upgrade ingress-controller ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \
  --namespace ingress-nginx \
  --set controller.metrics.enabled=true \
  --set-string controller.podAnnotations."prometheus\.io/scrape"="true" \
  --set-string controller.podAnnotations."prometheus\.io/port"="10254"
```

Let me know if this worked for you! :)

Comment: thanks for topics. very usefull.  additinaly how can I configure prometheus  outside the kuberntes cluster.